# Do Symbian OS v9 and Symbian^3 mean the same thing?

Tags: version, symbian

I am a little confused about the notations. What does Symbian^3 mean?
Also, how does Symbian^x relate to Symbian OS v9.y ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symbian^x != Symbian OS 9.y
The Symbian^x releases are built upon the original Symbian OS 9.4 release **plus** Nokia S60 layers. Since the base OS continues to evolve, though, its not useful to think in terms of the old 9.x numbering - we've moved beyond those now. What is worth noting, though, is that in general Symbian^x releases are backwards compatible with Symbian OS 9.y releases (though there are a few breaks - see the release notes for details).

Symbian^1 is the equivalent of Symbian OS 9.4 plus Nokia S60 5th edition layers (http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Symbian%5E1)

Symbian^2 is Symbian^1 plus a few fairly minor features (http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Symbian%5E2#Introduction)

Symbian^3 is focussed on UI and architecture improvements (http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Symbian%5E3_Developer_Overview)

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered several breaks in Symbian^3 that stop our current 3rd and 5th edition applications to work. So the backward compatibility is not absolute